# Run selenium grid tests through an executable file

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am writing selenium grid tests using, testng, xslt reports and ant in eclipse.

I would like to know what is the best way to export selenium tests + testng.xml in an executable file, batch file for example.

I have used export to Jar file option in eclipse and I have ended up with a  war file.

Is there any other option where I can run my tests through executable file?